# Creating async selects to WMI and wait to their completion

Tags: c#, asynchronous, methods, task

I read a lot of posts about async methods, but still... I'm a little confused about this. So maybe someone can help me with my case. Right now my code doesn't throw any error, but I know that my code is not good, cause I use async void and I can't wait for all my task to be completed.

So, can someone please help me edit this code:

In my form class, I create Relation:

```
Relation rel = new Relation(cb_MachineToConnect.Text);
```

In Relation class:

```
public Relation(string machineAddress)
    {
        isAsctive = true;
        idCount++;
        relationID = idCount;

        machine = new Machine(machineAddress);
        //I'm using WMI for gettig data from remote machine
        scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", machineAddress));
        scope.Options.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut);

        //In this method, I need run async part of code - WMI selects
        LoadMachineData();
    }
```

LoadMachineData methode code:

```
    private async void LoadMachineData()
    {
        try
        {
            scope.Connect();

            try
            {
                //List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<SelectQueryName, SelectQuery> select in SelectQueryes)
                {
                    //And this is it.. I need to run this methods async for better performance. SelectFromWMI is in Relation class and SetWMIproiperties is in Machine class
                    await Task.Run(() => machine.SetWMIProperties(select.Key, SelectFromWMI(select.Value, scope)));
                    //taskList.Add(t);
                    //machine.SetWMIProperties(select.Key, SelectFromWMI(select.Value, scope));
                }
                //I also want to wait for all created Tasks completion, but with this code it is not possible
                //Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventNotifier.LogOnScreen(string.Format("{0}, viz: {1}", ErrorList.GetEIbyID(15).definition, ex.Message));
                EventNotifier.Log(ex, ErrorList.GetEIbyID(15));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventNotifier.LogOnScreen(string.Format("{0}, viz: {1}", ErrorList.GetEIbyID(16).definition, ex.Message));
            EventNotifier.Log(ex, ErrorList.GetEIbyID(17));
        }
    }
```

SetWMIProperties(...) in Machine class:

```
    public void SetWMIProperties(SelectQueryName queryName, List<Dictionary<string, string>> propertiesData)
    {
        foreach (Dictionary<string, string> result in propertiesData)
        {
            switch (queryName)
            {
                case SelectQueryName.DiskModel:

                    disks.Add(result["Model"]);
                    break;

                case SelectQueryName.Drives:

                    drives.Add(new Drive { Name = result["Name"], FreeSpace = Convert.ToInt64(result["FreeSpace"]), Size = Convert.ToInt64(result["Size"]) });
                    break;

                case SelectQueryName.OS:

                    operatingSystem = new OS { BuildNumber = result["BuildNumber"], ProductName = result["Caption"], BitVersion = (result["OSArchitecture"].Contains(((int)OSBitVersion.Win32).ToString())) ? OSBitVersion.Win32 : OSBitVersion.Win64 };
                    break;

                case SelectQueryName.Processor:

                    processor = result["Name"];
                    break;

                case SelectQueryName.RAM:

                    ram = new RAM { TotalVisibleMemorySize = Convert.ToInt64(result["TotalVisibleMemorySize"]), FreePhysicalMemory = Convert.ToInt64(result["FreePhysicalMemory"]) };
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the WMI select method in Relation class  (in fact, this method should to be truly async, cause WMI select can sometimes be really slow):

```
    private static List<Dictionary<string, string>> SelectFromWMI(SelectQuery select, ManagementScope wmiScope)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> result = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiScope, select);
        ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in objectCollection)
        {
            result.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
            foreach (PropertyData property in managementObject.Properties)
            {
                result.Last().Add(property.Name, property.Value.ToString());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Blaato, what is the actual problem? Is it that you can't handle exceptions from your task?

Comment: @KozhevnikovDmitry No, exceptions are just fine, but I know that async void is a bad solution => LoadMachienData(), so i want to know how to do it right and the second is that in this solution a cannot wait for all tasks completion in LoadmachineData method. So I want tu run tasks in my example above, run them async and wait to completion of all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To await all your tasks you can use `Task.WhenAll()`:

```
private async void LoadMachineData()
{
    try
    {
        scope.Connect();

        try
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<SelectQueryName, SelectQuery> select in SelectQueryes)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => machine.SetWMIProperties(select.Key, SelectFromWMI(select.Value, scope))));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventNotifier.LogOnScreen(string.Format("{0}, viz: {1}", ErrorList.GetEIbyID(15).definition, ex.Message));
            EventNotifier.Log(ex, ErrorList.GetEIbyID(15));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventNotifier.LogOnScreen(string.Format("{0}, viz: {1}", ErrorList.GetEIbyID(16).definition, ex.Message));
        EventNotifier.Log(ex, ErrorList.GetEIbyID(17));
    }
}
```

To wait for completion of `LoadMachineData()` you can change it signature to `async Task` and call as `LoadMachineData().Wait()`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Greate, that's it, thank you! :) But only one thing.. After change LoadMachine data to async Task -> LoadMachineData().Wait() doesn't work -> it is infinite wait. So I use Task.Run(async () => { await LoadMachineData(); }).Wait(); instead and everything seems to be OK.

Comment: Hm. This is weird. Are you sure, that all tasks return control or throw an exception?

Comment: I just try debug everything again, and the LoadMachineData is really not finished, because Task.WhenAll is not finished, bud SetWMIProperties method which we run as a Task in LoadMachineData was just fine finished everytime, so I'm little confused.

Comment: When I use Task.WaitAll insted of Task.WhenAll everything is OK with LoadMachineData.Wait();

Comment: Hm. We have different environment possibly. I can add the working example with `WhenAll` and 'async Task'. Do you need it?

Comment: Another try and the problem is in await before the Task.WhenAll. Without await Task.WhenAll finished without problem.
Thank you, but you don't have to, I thing that WaitAll is ok for me too.

Comment: I suppose you actually need parallel instead of asynchronous execution. It this case your last version is the most approptiate.

Comment: I think you are right, because the mainly reason why I looking for solution is a performance.
your solution with `WaitAll` average time: 215 ms
Classic synchronious without Task using average time: 216 ms
Runnin selects in another thread without wait averege time: 139 ms
So I will use your edit with `WaitAll`, I think that thats the best one.