# Asynchronous Remote WMI Calls C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, wmi, remote-server

I'm really struggling to get WMI data from a remote host in an asynchronous way. After a lot of research, I can't find any clear examples, Microsoft's documentation only has VB and C++ code and there are even articles explaining why it's a bad idea. I've come from PowerShell, with that I would just create a new runspace to get the information.

I currently have a WPF window that I want to remain responsive whilst querying the information before updating the window. I've currently only managed to use synchronous calls using CimSession.Create and QueryInstance.

I would really appreciate some help with this :)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159471/creating-async-selects-to-wmi-and-wait-to-their-completion

Comment: @Hintham I read that but it didn't make much sense. Do you know if there is a simpler example or something that I can build up from? I can't seem to find any tutorials either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After proposing the same question to the MSDN forums, I got the correct answer and thought I would share it here as well :) I have put comments into the code to explain what is happening:

```
//Used to define what is returned in the async results
public static CimAsyncMultipleResults<CimInstance> GetValues(CimSession _session)
{
    return _session.QueryInstancesAsync(@"root\cimv2", "WQL", "SELECT Username FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
}

//This watches the async progress
class CimInstanceWatcher : IObserver<CimInstance>
{
    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    public void OnError(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
    }

    public void OnNext (CimInstance value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + value);
    }
}

private static void Main()
{
    //Leaving cimsession creation as sync because is happens "instantly"
    CimSession Session = CimSession.Create("PC-NAME");
    //Creating a new watcher object
    var instanceObject = new CimInstanceWatcher();
    //Subscribing the watcher object to the async call
    GetValues(Session).Subscribe(instanceObject);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) async methods to do async WMI work. For example:

```
WMIHelper helper = new WMIHelper("root\\CimV2");
List<Processor> processors = await helper.QueryAsync<Processor>().ToList();
```

Comment: How would I use this in a distributed program though? wouldn't it need to be installed on ever machine?

Comment: No. Just make multiple connections. To do remote WMI work you will need a domain user.